# Strange behavior with html buttons

Tags: html, button, onclick

I am encountering a weird problem with buttons in a page.
I have three buttons as action buttons, but the third button click event is never called. 
Basically the functionality of 3 buttons are "Prev", "Next", "Exit". initially "Prev" button is disabled. Now both "next" and "Exit" buttons are enabled. The click event on the "Next" is working but the click event on "Exit" is not working. When i hover my mouse the hover function also does not work on this button.
But when i click "Next" now it automatically  starts working. I have no idea what is going on.
Here is the code for buttons

```
<div id="controls">
                <input type="button" id="prev" name="prev" value="Prev" disabled="" />
                <input type="button" id="next" name="next" value="Next" />
                <input type="button" id="exit" name="exit" value="Exit" />
</div>
```

The binding for these buttons are as follows -

```
$('#next').bind('click', next);
$('#prev').bind('click', prev);
$('#exit').bind('click', exit);
```

I have tried to replace the button with another button, tried a different javascript function but nothing works.
Also if i interchange "next" and "Exit" buttons, now "Exit" will work and "next" will not work. This is really getting annoying. I have tried all sort of debugging but no luck

any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: careful with keywords, change your callback name to exitt

Comment: @JonathandeM. no keywords there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: What are you doing the the next, prev and exit functions? Could you share the code here?

Comment: right now i just have console.log statements in those functions. Here are the functions.

Comment: function next() {
    console.log("next");
 }
 
 function prev() {
   console.log("prev");
 }

function exit() {
    console.log("exit");
}

Comment: @MattBall Could still be keywords, in jquery .next() and .prev() are existing functions. http://api.jquery.com/prev/, http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: call them something random and try again?

Comment: Your code looks fine. I don't see any hover function but click functionality is working. Maybe you should wrap it with `$(document).ready(function(){...});` Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/QVHD5/2/).

Comment: @JanR no, really, that's not the problem. A function name is not a keyword, and jQuery's `next`/`prev` functions aren't in the global namespace. Suggestions otherwise are no more than FUD.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If no then please upload your complete html, so that we can make changes to that and get back to you